# How to determine on which screen the taskbar is

Tags: java, javafx

So if i open my java application I want it to open on the screen on which I moved the taskbar.
Important to note is that the taskbar is not always on the Primary Screen. You can move it to secondary screens.
It would also be ideal to determine on which side the taskbar is(top, bottom, left, right)

Comment: No way to do this in the standard JavaFX library (or the standard Java library, as far as I know). If this is possible, you might have to drop to native code via JNI or JNA (or find a library that wraps the necessary native calls in a Java API for you).